# ClearCase: Files in 2 branches obscure each other

Tags: file, merge, clearcase, obscured-view

I have checked in the same file (filename) twice in 2 different branches (say, development and release).

This breaks just about anything, so I want to take 1 version and "properly" copy/merge it to the other branch, later merging in the lost changes manually (from a backup). Then I would lose history for 1 file but at least the 2 files would be connected again.

How to do it?

---

Also note, since the connection is broken, I cannot mere, also, when doing a Version Tree, both files have different version trees. (It is not 2 views at different files in 1 Version Tree, like is the normal/correct case.)

Also, I assume the problem is with the folder having some kind of a reference to 2 different files, but somehow, I cannot edit the folder?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are call "[evil twins](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21125072)" (also described in that [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636712/evil-twin-problem-and-subtractive-merge))
([one less thing to worry with Git ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910044/does-git-have-evil-twin-issues) )

The easiest way is to pick one branch:

- remove the file from the other branch (rmname),
- and to the merge.

The merge will add that same file in the other branch.
That process (`rmname` + `merge`) is illustrated in "[Clearcase: How do I merge in a specific file from one view, into another, to avoid the Evil Twin scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209342/clearcase-how-do-i-merge-in-a-specific-file-from-one-view-into-another-to-avo)"

---

(edit by Andreas)
Your solution worked great, I changed it for me since I noticed I have a specific case:
The file got bad since someone else renamed it... so it was not just as simple as your solution, but I had to do it "by hand", as is

Go to `X:\FullyQualifiedPath` (correct path in VOB)

Use:

```
cleartool ln FullyQualifiedName ./FileName
```

where `FullyQualifiedName` is the name as you get it e. g. from VersionTree when you say “`Send To -> Copy`” (something like `//view`, drop the `file:` before). This creates the link

Afterwards, you can see the desired version in the ClearCase Explorer again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added my way, similar to one in a post referenced by you (using cleartool ln). Worked great.
Looking froward to using a different Version Control System again soon. :)

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the feedback. I have added your edit to the answer.