# How to add renamed file as new file in clearcase?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I have file `Filename1.c` added to version control. I renamed it to `Filename2.c`.
Now I need to add another file with the name of `Filename1.c` to source control under same parent folder.

I am facing a twin error while adding new file with both names (Filename1.c and Filename2.c).

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are likely running a schema 80, feature level 7 or better VOB, and this is intentional behavior to prevent problems resulting from "identical" files that aren't.

The VOB owner user may be able to add the files to source control anyway. Failing that, the VOB owner or a CC admin use should be able to downgrade the evil twin detection level using

```
cleartool protectvob –evil_twin_warn ...
```

If you're not running on a schema 80 VOB, it means you have evil twin detection triggers, in which case you need to talk to whoever manages those...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in "[solution for clearcase evil twins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27635705/6309)", a rename affects only the current version of the parent folder: after the rename, a version tree of the parent folder would show a new version, which list the same file under a new name.

It is better to cleartool rmname it, check-in, then add it again under a different name

See also "[RECOVER FROM EVIL TWINS](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21125072)":

> You have two choices to resolve the problem.
>
> 1. Rename one of the elements using the `cleartool mv` command.
> 2. Remove one of the elements using the `cleartool rmelem` command.
>
> Note : If in a UCM environment, you will need to first rename the element (using `cleartool mv`) and then remove the name using `cleartool rmname`.
>   The reason is that removing elements in UCM using `cleartool rmelem` is not recommended as it can negatively affect your configuration.
>   Review [technote 1119222](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21119222) for more information about removing elements in UCM.