# Merged file not showing up in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

In ClearCase, I merged file `ABC` to a branch. This resulted in Version 1 in the version tree. I labeled it `LAB_A1`.

Later, I merged file `XYZ` to the same branch. This resulted in Version 2 in the version tree. I labeled it `LAB_X1`.

File `ABC` is missing in `LAB_X1` and in the version tree Version 2.
I checked out Version 2 and tried to merge file `ABC`, ClearCase comes back stating there’s nothing to merge.
According to ClearCase file ABC already exists on Version 2.
In the version tree I did a diff between Versions 1 and 2.
You can clearly see the file `ABC` is missing from Version 2.

I need both files `ABC` and `XYZ`, in the latest version.
How do I do this?

I merged to our development branch.

Config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * LAB_X1 
element lost+found -none 
element * /main/0 -mkbranch DEV
```

When using label LAB_X1 in the config spec I can see file XYZ, but not ABC. I can see file ABC if I use LAB_A1 in my config spec.

Comment: I merged to our development branch. 

Config spec:
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * LAB_X1
element lost+found -none
element * /main/0 -mkbranch DEV

When using label LAB_X1 in the config spec I can see file XYZ, but not ABC.
I can see file ABC if I use LAB_A1 in my config spec.

Answer (score 1):

You may edit your config spec (`cleartool edcs`) to show the latest version on your branch.

This should be enough for your case:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../DEV/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch DEV
```

In this scenario, it doesn't care about labels at all and just selects the latest version of the directory and the files in it by first looking for the `DEV` branch and secondly for the `main` branch. With this change, both your files should become visible.

If the actual files don't have a `DEV` branch, you may need the labels too to select the versions you've labelled:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../DEV/LATEST
element * LAB_X1 -mkbranch DEV
element * LAB_A1 -mkbranch DEV
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch DEV
```

or simpler, add `mkbranch DEV` to all the rules that follows after the `.../DEV/LATEST` rule:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../DEV/LATEST
mkbranch DEV
element * LAB_X1
element * LAB_A1
element * /main/LATEST
```

Answer (score 0):

> This resulted in Version 2 in the version tree.

That would be version 2 for the parent folder, not the file itself.

> File ABC is missing in LAB_X1 and in the version tree Version 2.

It depends on your config spec, whose selection rules order matters.

But assuming those are correct, you can start and simply re-create file `ABC` in a checked out version of the parent folder, creating a version 3.

At most, you could have evil twins, but if you don't mind working from now on with that new `ABC` file, you should be fine.

However, the config spec you mention does not work for new elements, as it lacks a `/main/LATEST` backstop rule.

Comment: Most organizations who's suffered from evil twins would have triggers to prevent them though. I wouldn't suggest creating them as a solution :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo True (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27635705/6309). Your config spec should be enough.